# MVC3 TempData exists when clicking back button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using TempData to pass additional messages to show a notification accross requests:

```
    public ActionResult Address()
            TempData["NotificationType"] = "error";
            TempData["NotificationMessage"] = "There was an error updating the address.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {          

        if (TempData["NotificationType"] != null && TempData["NotificationMessage"] != null)
        {
            model.NotificationMessage = TempData["NotificationMessage"].ToString();
            model.NotificationType = TempData["NotificationType"].ToString();
        }
     return View();
    }
```

Index View:

```
<div id="NotificationType" data-notification_type="@Model.NotificationType"/>
<div id="NotificationMessage" data-notification_message="@Model.NotificationMessage" />

<script type=text/javascript>
if($('#NotificationType').data('notification_type') == 'error'){
    Notify('error', "Error!", $('#NotificationMessage').data('notification_message'));
    }
</script>
```

I then display the error notification in the view and it works great. 
My problem comes in after that if I click another link and then press the back button in the browser the notification displays again.

Is there a way to prevent the notification from redisplaying?

**EDIT:** Looks like its because its caching the index view as it doesn't hit a breakpoint in the action when I hit the back button.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed this by preventing caching on the index view:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Index()
```

Comment: After hours of searching finally found the right solution. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

For .net core 3.0 or higher you can make use of this on your index view

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //Your code here..
}
```

Happy coding.